# Closures definition and usage in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, closures

I'm trying to write a generic function to start and end events into my Obj-C (iOS) application. I'm defining `- (void)startEvent:(void (^)())completion`. In the body of this function I take an action that launches an animation. What I need is call to `completion` when an specific time interval pass.

So, I make a copy of `completion` and assign it to a global variable (in class scope).

This is how I do this:

```
void (^startEventCompletionClosure)();

- (void)startEvent:(void (^)())completion {
    // side note: I have NO access to "complete" closure of - [UIView animateWithDuration:...]
    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(startEventCompleted) withObject:nil afterDelay:kDealy];
    startEventCompletionClosure = [completion copy];
}

- (void)startEventCompleted {
    startEventCompletionClosure();
    [startEventCompletionClosure release];
}
```

But, I have a few questions:

- Is this the better way to handle this?
- Is a __block an NSObject? a C declaration?
- Why do I have to `copy` it? Is it not possible just to `retain` it?
- If it's not an Obj-C Object, why I can call to `[... copy]` and `[... retain]` as it were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the better way to handle this?

Depending on your usage, you may want to store this as an instance variable (unless you really want the block to be shared between classes, and thus changed for *all* classes anytime `startEvent:` is called).

> Is a __block an NSObject? a C declaration?

It's a C storage qualifier.

> Why do I have to copy it? Is it not possible just to retain it?

You can retain it, but it probably won't do what you want it to do. In C and Objective-C, blocks are created on the stack. When you copy it, it (and any variables it closed over) are copied to the heap. If you retain it, it and its variables are *not* copied to the heap.

> If it's not an Obj-C Object, why I can call to `[... copy]` and `[... retain]` as it were?

Magic. :) More seriously, in Objective-C, blocks are designed to act as Objective-C objects. (It's similar to the reason you can seamlessly cast between `NSString` and `CFStringRef` -- the objects are designed to make this possible.)

Answer (score 1):

First, we call them "blocks", not "closures" in Objective-C.  Secondly, `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is something we used before we had blocks.  These days, you should probably use `dispatch_after()`.  Finally, blocks *are* objects, and they conform to the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a look to `dispatch_after`.

Answer (score 0):

UIView also has nice block based animation methods now...

animateWithDuration:animations:
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDurationTime animations:^{
    // animate some animatable properties
    // do some other stuff
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // code that you want to run
    //  when the animation has finished
}];
```

I've found this a very useful way to animate things.

Comment: for whoever downvoted this, I realise I'm not answering the specific question of the title, but I am in fact answering bullet point #1 of Gonzalo's questions: "Is this the better way to handle this?"  Given that animateWithDuration:completion offers what he seems to be attempting without having to write any additional code, I would call this a valid answer.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because I couldn't (and I can't) find any relation between what I asked and your answer. Sorry, and thanks for your time anyway. My question at that time was about executing something after a delay, not after an animation, and a general question about blocks. Cheers.